# Google Directory user list from an app

Tags: ios, oauth, google-api, google-admin-sdk, service-accounts

I am creating an iOS app for internal use. We have a Google Domain. As part of the functionality of the app, I want to be able to search for all users in that domain. This can already be done in Gmail, the Apple Mail app, and others.

I found that you can use [the Admin SDK for users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) to do exactly what I want to do. I created a Client ID for the iOS app and authorized my app to perform `users.list`.

[image: Permissions in developer console]

However, now I get a permissions error for users who sign in with OAuth2:

[image: OAuth authorized user not authorized to list users]

I found that [you can create a service account to make API requests on your behalf](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) if you delegate it to have the authority. I'm not sure if this is what I want to do since this seems more like something for a secure server to do rather than an app. I'm also not sure how this integrates with a user (from our domain) who signs in with OAuth being able to list our users.

Is it possible to list/search the users in a Google domain purely through OAuth / frontend app?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from caching your own list, I think there are two ways to give users the ability to list all users:

A. Undocumented call to this GAL API: 
`https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/gal/your-domain-goes-here/full?alt=json` ([source](https://github.com/google/gfw-deployments/blob/master/apps/shell/gal/gal_feed.sh)). You can test this in the [Google OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) by selecting the scope for the Contacts V3 API or using the string `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/`.

B. In the Admin console, create an "all users" group. Assign to a newly created Admin Role. Grant the admin role "read" in Privileges > Admin API Privileges > Users > Read (checked).